# JS Regex match URL inside contenteditable doesn't work properly with www.*

Tags: javascript

I have a `contenteditable` where users write stuff like:

```
Hello
 www.stackoverflow.com
```

And I want to replace the links with `<a href>`. I have this working perfectly for URL's starting with `http://` or `https://`, but not for `www`. When the user writes:

```
Hello
 www.stackoverflow.com
```

The HTML of the `contenteditable` is:

[image]

You can see a live **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aed2ygp8/3/)** & the regex I'm using was taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/kiennt2/c9a489369562c424c793b8883b98802e):

```
var str = html.replace(/\b(https?:\/\/[^\s\(\)\'\"\<\>]+)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
str = str.replace(/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>');
```

Comment: And what's with all the other subdomains, and sub-sub-domains and ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this slightly different. My answer however is not perfect though; URLs are tricky business.

```
function go(){
  var html = $('.content').html();
  html = html.replace(/(?:(?:(?:https?|ftps?)?:?)\/\/)?w{3,}.?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff][a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9\u00a1-\uffff]\.)+(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}\.?))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?/igm, (url) => '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>');
  $('.result').html(html);
}
```

Comment: This will throw errors, for more help with URL Regex and why this is difficult google perfect URL regex there's a chart.

Comment: Just be sure and run it through a list of links, if it fails in a way you don't like, try again! :D